# If a canvas does not shown in the viewport, does it consuming resources the same as the canvas inside viewport?

Tags: css, canvas

like

```
  #someCanvas{
    position: fixed;
    right: -200vw;
  }
```

move canvas outside of visible zone, does it consuming resources the same as the canvas inside the visible zone?

Answer (score 0):

The `canvas` logic will continue to run whether it's visible or off screen.

If you're looking for a way to improve performance of canvas and don't need it to be on screen, you can try using `OffscreenCanvas` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OffscreenCanvas